# Создать и вывести картинку - Base64 - PHP

Tags: php, base64

Доброго времени. Создаю и вывожу я картинку с телефоном так:

```
header("Content-Type: image/png");
$im = @imagecreate(150, 20)or die("Невозможно создать поток изображения");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 4, 2, 2,  "+7 111 111 11 11", $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

далее, мне нужно сразу ее вывести, но только в base64. Подскажите логику моих дальнейших действий, а то не соображу: нужно копировать на хост ее и потом выводить или можно без копирования, сразу ее вывести, чтобы место не занимала ?

Вывожу другие картинки на хосте так :

```
$file = "../../../../../demo/8.x/test.png";
if($fp = fopen($file,"rb", 0))
{
   $picture = fread($fp,filesize($file));
   fclose($fp);
   $base64 = chunk_split(base64_encode($picture));
   $tag = '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,'.$base64.'" />';
    echo $tag;
}
```

пример : авито

Comment: Постмотрите здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338695/php-gd-library-output-an-image-and-text-content-on-same-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Главное: генерировать картинку с номером телефона на лету - очень плохая мысль. Это тяжёлая операция и ваша железка загнётся уже на какой-то совершенно смешной нагрузке.

Создавайте картинку сразу при создании объявления и кладите её с каким-нибудь именем, не содержащем в себе исходный номер телефона. В сущности, md5 от телефона с какой-нибудь глобальной для проекта строкой уже будет достаточно. Прячетесь ведь только от глупых парсеров, которые не будут разбирать написанное на картинке, а написано-то без всяких искажений, контрастно. Соответственно, вставлять картинку инлайном в base64 или обычным src - уже не имеет особой разницы.

Либо, как другой вариант, генерировать картинку при первом обращении к ней и сохранять куда-нибудь в кеш.

Если работать с диском стало тесно (например, хотите кэш картинок в `memcached` засунуть), а `tempnam` использовать не спортивно (и, тем более, по какой-то причине хотите куцый `GD2`, а не `imagemagick`), то встаёт вопрос, как получить бинарник сгенерированной картинки в строку. GD штатных средств для этого не даёт, но можно обойтись буферизацией вывода:

```
$im = @imagecreate(150, 20)or die("Невозможно создать поток изображения");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 4, 2, 2,  "+7 111 111 11 11", $text_color);
ob_start();
imagepng($im);
$img = ob_get_clean();
imagedestroy($im);
// в $img теперь лежит сгенерированный бинарник
```

Comment: спасибо. Вполне конструктивно написали .. Учту

Answer (score 2):

```html
<?php
$image = 'img/phone.png';
$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));
$src = 'data: '.mime_content_type($image).';base64,'.$imageData;



echo "<img src=\"$src\" alt=\"\" />";
?>
```

вот - это очень просто , решение на SO.com сложное

```html
<?php


$path = 'img/pic.jpg';
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);

echo "<img src=\"$base64\" alt=\"\" />";


?>
```

это второй вариант - только проверил : рабочий , вот что выводит данные скрипты :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]